# ChunkLoadError Chrome Extension Failure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, single-page-application

I have a React app bundled with webpack and when refreshing with dev tools open, I get the following error:

> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 868 failed. (error: chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/868.6e8bcbc51918bd56.js

The console says:

> Denying load of chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/868.6e8bcbc51918bd56.js. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

It subsequently experiences a network error as well, but I'm not sure if that's purely because of the previous error:

> GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

It seems this is caused by React Dev Tools, as that is the extension ID listed in the error, and when disabling the Chrome extension, this is not a problem.

The app uses code splitting with React lazy as well, hence the chunks.

I have tried to create a manifest.json file to allow the React Dev Tools extension to access whatever it needs.

```
manifest.json

{
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "resources": ["fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/*.js"],
    "extension_ids": ["fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Remove fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi from `resources`.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing that and updating the `web_accessible_resources` to just
`"extension_ids": ["fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi"]`
yields the same result.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. Remove exactly what I said from `resources` and leave the rest of `resources`.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. I updated resources to `"resources": ["/build/*.js"]` and it looks like that worked!